# Suppress command window when running console application on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, command-line, windows-xp

Is there a way to suppress showing the command window when running a console application on Windows XP?

Details: I am calling a (console-based) program from Vim.  I would like to avoid the command window being shown every time I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try [shell.vim](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/shell/)?

> **The xolox#shell#execute() function**
>
> This function enables other Vim
> plug-ins to execute external commands
> in the background (i.e.
> asynchronously) *without opening a
> command prompt* window on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Try `start /B <program name>` to start the program without a new window.

Comment: This is a good answer (so +1) that works from a cmd window.  However, `start` seems to be a builtin command of cmd.exe, which means that I can't use it without starting a cmd.exe first.  This means I cannot use it from within Vim.

Comment: Hm? :!start seems to be a vim command. So for example `:!start /b cmd /c "explorer.exe"` will open an explorer window without creating a console or displaying it.

Comment: @AchalDave: No, start is not a vim command there.  `:!` means to execute the rest in a command shell, so you're just calling the `cmd.exe` `start` command there.

Comment: Thank you for an answer that avoids using an external plugin. This should be the accepted answer imo. @Szabolcs, does the command window show for you when using `start` as a vim external command? It doesn't for me...

Comment: @MichaelMurphy Sorry, this question was asked ~10 years ago and I no longer use Windows. I expect things may have changed.

Answer (score 3):

i can't believe no one has suggested simply using **:silent**

for example, I have the following in my .vimrc (gvim on Win7)

```
"open windows explorer to the directory of the current file
:map <leader>ex :silent !Explorer %:p:h<CR>
```

Comment: I am not on Windows at the moment, but doesn't this only suppress messages *inside* Vim? What I needed was suppressing the black Command Prompt window that popped up every time.

Comment: i copied that line from my .vimrc, it works well for me. without it, i need to press enter twice after executing !explorer -- once to discard the cmd window that pops up, and again in gvim in the command bar at the bottom.

Comment: The question was not about pressing enter.  It was about suppressing the window completely.  I didn't want a window flashing up every time a certain action is executed.

Comment: I see. Then you are correct, :silent doesn't help with that, the cmd windows still flashes momentarily.

Answer (score 3):

When I didn’t want to see the output of external commands called from the Vim command line, I would prepend them with `:silent`. However, this results in a command window momentarily flashing on screen when running GVim under MS Windows. After a short while, I got annoyed by this behaviour so I researched alternative solutions (which is how I came across this question).

---

The best solution I came up with was to use Vim’s inbuilt [`system` function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system()) which runs shell commands without opening an external command window. While the output of the shell command is not printed, its exit status is conveniently available via `v:shell_error`. It also has the advantage that it’s portable across (all) platforms.

Example (the `echo` statement should print `0` if `C:\Windows` exists):

```
call system("dir c:\windows")
echo v:shell_error
```

Comment: The `system` function is great when you want that there is no external command window.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use some autohotkey script of this kind:

```
Loop {
    WinWait, my command window title
    WinHide
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use git-bash as my shell from vim on Windows but having the command prompt open whenever a command was run, as you described. My eventual solution was to install the plugin `xolox/vim-shell` and add the following snippet to `.vimrc`:

```
if has('win32')
        set shell=bash\ -c
        set shellcmdflag=
        set shellxquote='
        set shellquote=
        set shellredir=>
        set noshelltemp "This prevents an external window from opening.
endif
```

Answer (score -1):

This utility will also do the job:

http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html